# Live update values from DB in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to do a script in PHP that updates two values when they change in a mySQL database. My issue is that it doesn't work. As I am not used to php, I assume it need to run the whole script before it outputs the echo. There for I dont get any echo output in my while-loop.

I want to erase the old values when new ones arrived, thats the reason for the ob_end_clean(); command.

I would love some help here on how I can solve it! I do not want to refresh the whole page, just output new values when they change in the database.

Thank you in advance!

```
    <?php
    //DB INFO
     $db = mysqli_connect('test.domain.mysql','test_domain_test','testtest','test_domain_test')
     or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    ?>

    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
     <h1>IFRAME</h1>

    <?php
    ob_start();
    $tempSensor1 = 0;
    $tempSensor2 = 0;

    //Get values
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `values`";
    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');


    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //Writes to the page the latest value in the table.
    echo $row['sensor1'] . $row['sensor2'] . '<br />';

   // Saves the values temporarily.
    $tempSensor1 = $row['sensor1'];
    $tempSensor2 = $row['sensor2'];

   //Infinity loop to update the values if the changes.    
    while(1){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `values`";
    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //If new values in DB, write these out.   
    if($row['sensor1'] != $tempSensor1 or $row['sensor2'] != $tempSensor2) {
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $row['sensor1'] . $row['sensor2'] . '<br />';
    }
    $tempSensor1 = $row['sensor1'];
    $tempSensor2 = $row['sensor2'];
    sleep(5);
    }

    //Close connection to DB
    mysqli_close($db);

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: that's not how this should work. you can't "erase" what was already sent to the client with the ob() functions. and your query structure is wrong too. you'll always get SOME rows back anyways, since you're comparing many records against only two values.

Comment: Yeah I figured.. Im used to C programming so this is a bit new to me. Any ideas on how I can manage to get the end result I am looking for?

Comment: ajax/websockets to poll the server, or have updates pushed out, and some JS code to rip out the old data and display the updates.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use NodeRED to push the updates out to the PHP page, I think that could work, right?